# How to display histogram of RGB values of an image?

Tags: java, android, image, graph, histogram

My application captures an image and applies a filter to it to modify the image RGB values.

Once modified, I wish to display a histogram of each colour (Red, Green, Blue) on top of the image itself.

I already know how to get RGB values and I already know how to get the Bitmap, I just dont know how to plot them.

code for RGB values:

```
    int[] pixels = new int[width*height];
    int index = 0;
    image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    Bitmap returnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            A = (pixels[index] >> 24) & 0xFF;
            R = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            G = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            B = pixels[index] & 0xFF;
                            ++index;

                     }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

We had done something similar. We got the Bitmap of the image with:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(<youImageView>.getResources(), R.drawable.some_drawable);
```

We then iterated over every Pixel and used following piece of code to get the Colors of the Pixel:

```
int color = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
int[] rgbValues = new int[]{
                (color >> 16) & 0xff, //red
                (color >>  8) & 0xff, //green
                (color      ) & 0xff  //blue
            };
```

**Edit:**
I just read that you can also get the opacity by using this insead:

```
int color = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
int[] rgbValues = new int[]{
                (color >> 24) & 0xff, //alpha
                (color >> 16) & 0xff, //red
                (color >>  8) & 0xff, //green
                (color      ) & 0xff  //blue
            };
```

---

If you already have the values, I would recommend you [androidplot](http://androidplot.com/) to create the graphs. There are some examples that make it easy to use. I haven't worked with bar-charts, but line charts worked fine. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/master/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/BarPlotExampleActivity.java?at=master) is an example of BarCharts for androidplot.
And I would just sum up the different values and then (if you want to) normalize it.

---

To finally display the graphs, you may create the layout as a FrameLayout and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481183/how-to-android-z-order) might help you working the the z-order. The only thing you have to do now, is showing/hiding the part of the layout, containing your graphs. ([`View.setVisibility`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29))

Comment: Hi, see my updated question, I already know how to get the RGB values, I just dont know how I can plot them based on the captured image

Comment: Hey, please see my edited version of the answer. Hope this helps.